# Property and setter decorators not running in subclass

Tags: python

I hope someone can help.  I am using the book “Python (2nd Edition): Learn Python In One Day And Learn It Well”.

I have worked through the project and am just catching final bugs but there is one that is leaving my completely stumped.

The game that’s being coded provides options of two games to the user. It then provides an option for the number of questions they want to answer.  Each game is a subclass of the Game class.  In the Game class there are decorators for getter and setter but these do not get called...ever!  It won’t even print the lines I added to debug.  My understanding was that if these are defined in the base class, then they will be initialised by the subclasses unless overridden.

I’ve checked my code with the answers in the book and I’ve checked the syntax and it all looks good. I also haven’t found any other questions that have helped.

Also I’m using Pythonista for all of this. Not sure if it could be a bug with that?

Below is the class code, not sure if the actual program helps at this stage but I can post if necessary

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
class Game:
    def __init__ (self, noOfQuestions = 0):
        self._noOfQuestions = noOfQuestions # the underscored argument has property definitions

        @property # returns one as the other when queried
        def noOfQuestions(self):
            print('getter')
            return self._noOfQuestions

        @noOfQuestions.setter # to set the value it needs to meet the parameters below
        def noOfQuestions(self, value):
            print('1st line')
            if value < 1:
                print('2nd line')
                self._noOfQuestions = 1
                print('The minimum number of questions is one, so there will be one.')
            elif (value > 10):
                print('3rd line')
                self._noOfQuestions = 10
                print('The maximum number of questions is ten, so there will be ten.')
            else :
                print('4th line')
                self._noOfQuestions = value

class BinaryGame(Game): # a sub class of Game
    def generateQuestions(self): #this will generate binary numbers, get the user response and compare
        from random import randint
        score = 0 # initialise score to zero

        for q in range(self.noOfQuestions): # for the number of questions
            base10 = randint(1, 100) # generate a random int between 1 and 100
            userResult = input('\nPlease enter the binary version of %d' %(base10)) # user to enter binary version
            while True: # until broken
                try:    # try to cast the int as binary
                    answer = int(userResult, base = 2) 
                    if answer == base10: # compare the user answer to the correct answer
                        print('\nThat is correct, well done!')
                        score += 1 # add 1 to the score
                        break
                    else:
                        print('\nThat is incorrect, are you an idiot? The correct answer is {:b}.' .format(base10))
                        break
                except : # if they didn't type in a binary number
                    print('\nAnswer must be base-2 (binary), please try again.')
                    userResult = input('\nPlease enter the binary version of %d' %(base10))
        return score


class MathGame(Game): #sub class of Game
    def generateQuestions(self): 
        from random import randint # import randint
        score = 0 # set the score to zero

        numberList = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #initiate number list
        symbolList = ['', '', '', ''] # initiate symbol list
        operatorDict = {1 : "+", 2 : "-", 3 : "*", 4 : "**"} # dictionary of opperators

        for q in range(self.noOfQuestions): #for the number of questions

            for i in range(0,5): #generate random numbers into the number list
                numberList[i] = randint(1,9)

            for i in range(0, 4): # generate random symbols into symbol list avoiding adjacent **
                if i > 0 and symbolList[i-1] == "**": 
                    symbolList[i] = operatorDict[randint(1, 3)]
                else:
                    symbolList[i] = operatorDict[randint(1, 4)]

            questionString = str(numberList[0]) # add the final number to the string

            for i in range(0, 4): # for each item in the symbol list add a number and symbol
                questionString = questionString + symbolList[i] + str(numberList[i+1])

            result = eval(questionString) # caluclate the correct answer
            questionString = questionString.replace("**", "^") # swap ** for ^

            userResult = input('Solve %s' %(questionString))

            while True: # get an answer, check it's an int and then check if it's correct
                try:            
                    answer = int(userResult)
                    if answer == result:
                        print("\nWell done, that's correct")
                        score =+1
                        break
                    else:
                        print('\nBad luck dumbass, the answer is %s' %(result))
                        break
                except ValueError:
                    print('\nValue must be an integer')
                    userResult = input('Solve %s' %(questionString))
        return score
```

Comment: Well, if you took out all your game code, limited your post to just the code specific to the property calls between the 2 classes, you'd probably get better answers.  Post also the output and/or the error messages and/or expectations.  Narrow it down, basically - because right now nothing seems like it's very complicated, except for having to read all of your code first.  And... also sometimes, when you really simplify and strip code to show sample behavior, the cause of the error becomes obvious to you.  Welcome aboard.

Comment: In Game class, the function are stated inside __init__ function. Seems to be a problem of indent of `def noOfQuestions(self, value):` and `def noOfQuestions(self, value):`. Dedent them

Comment: errr... never mind.  given the indent issue, posting a smaller code sample would not have been illustrative of your problem.  although... you might have caught the indent yourself when trying to code a minimal sample.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Wish I’d spotted that and indentation has tripped me up with a few things so I should have known better to check that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to "dedent" the function in Game Class:

```
class Game:
    def __init__ (self, noOfQuestions = 0):
        self._noOfQuestions = noOfQuestions # the underscored argument has property definitions
    # -------------------------------------------------------------
    # following function moved backward at same level as __init__()
    # -------------------------------------------------------------

    @property # returns one as the other when queried
    def noOfQuestions(self):
        print('getter')
        return self._noOfQuestions

    @noOfQuestions.setter # to set the value it needs to meet the parameters below
    def noOfQuestions(self, value):
        print('1st line')
        if value < 1:
            print('2nd line')
            self._noOfQuestions = 1
            print('The minimum number of questions is one, so there will be one.')
        elif (value > 10):
            print('3rd line')
            self._noOfQuestions = 10
            print('The maximum number of questions is ten, so there will be ten.')
        else :
            print('4th line')
            self._noOfQuestions = value
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an indentation problem, your getter/setter are defined in your `__init__` function.

You need to unindent:

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self, noOfQuestions=0):
        self._noOfQuestions = noOfQuestions  # the underscored argument has property definitions

    # <!-- UNINDENT HERE, LIKE THIS: -->

    @property  # returns one as the other when queried
    def noOfQuestions(self):
        print('getter')
        return self._noOfQuestions

    @noOfQuestions.setter  # to set the value it needs to meet the parameters below
    def noOfQuestions(self, value):
        print('1st line')
        if value < 1:
            print('2nd line')
            self._noOfQuestions = 1
            print('The minimum number of questions is one, so there will be one.')
        elif value > 10:
            print('3rd line')
            self._noOfQuestions = 10
            print('The maximum number of questions is ten, so there will be ten.')
        else:
            print('4th line')
            self._noOfQuestions = value
```

Comment: You should use the [PEP 8 Naming convention](https://pep8.org/#naming-conventions): so, turn `noOfQuestions` into `no_of_questions`.